# how to trim trailing spaces in teradata table columns

Tags: teradata, trim

i want to trim trailing spaces for teradata table columns,

i do it like this,

```
trim(trailing from dictionary_managed_databases.dbname),
```

or use trim directly,

```
trim(dictionary_managed_databases.dbname),
```

but the result shows:
[image]

seems the trim do not work, 
not sure how to do it in teradata,

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? I mean... your screenshot doesn't exactly show any spaces after the words?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @dnoeth How is it that after 8 hours of this question sitting out here we both manage to throw nearly the same comment on it at the exact same second...  I'm spooked.

Comment: @JNevill: It's magic :-)

Comment: @JNevill there is the third columns returned, only at the far right side, and is invisible, that is why i think it doesn't work

Comment: Perhaps it's just the column width? Is this a CHAR() or VARCHAR() field? What client are you using to display this? Also...perhaps it's not a space character? Can you share the output of `CHAR2HEXINT(dictionary_managed_databases.dbname)`

Comment: @JNevill thanks a lot, i need to look at from the laptop tomorrow, now i am using my phone, it is 4:30am for me

Comment: Id' be curious what the output of `trim(trailing from dictionary_managed_databases.dbname) || '~'` is as well. If that tilde is way off the map, then it's probably not a space. The `CHAR2HEXINT` function will reveal what it really is.

Comment: This looks like report output from BTEQ where the default width is 80. And when you TRIM a column which is probably defined as Varchar(128) the size of that column is still 128 chars. Use `.set width 200` before the Select (or switch to a different client).

Comment: type of this field is "dbname VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET UNICODE", and i use BTEQ,  and the output of CHAR2HEXINT(dictionary_managed_databases.dbname) is like this  "0074006500730074",

Comment: i run this "trim(trailing from dictionary_managed_databases.dbname) || '~'", and there is no space between trim result and '~', that means trim works, but why the output of this field in BTEQ take  the width as long as just like char(128)

Answer (score 1):

```
create volatile table test ( dbname varchar(128) CHARACTER SET UNICODE ) on commit preserve rows;
insert into test values ( 'Database-Name' );
-- you don't need to trim a varchar column
select dbname || '~'  from test;
(dbname||'~')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Database-Name~
-- it is always max length, so not to loose any possible content
select trim(dbname) || '~'  from test;
(Trim(BOTH FROM dbname)||'~')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Database-Name~
-- you may cast it to shorten the resulting column
select cast(trim(dbname) as varchar(30)) from test;
Trim(BOTH FROM dbname)
------------------------------
Database-Name
-- it will never be less then the header, even if the content is less
select cast(trim(dbname) as varchar(10)) from test;
Trim(BOTH FROM dbname)
----------------------
Database-N
-- but it will truncate the result
select cast(trim(dbname) as varchar(10)) as dbname from test;
dbname
----------
Database-N
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sel 
dictionary_object_map.moId,
trim(dictionary_managed_databases.dbname)|| '~',
dictionary_deployed_info.dictionaryId,
dictionary_deployed_info.dictionaryName,
dictionary_managed_objects.moname
from dictionary_object_map,
dictionary_deployed_info,
dictionary_managed_objects ,
dictionary_managed_databases
where 
dictionary_object_map.dictionaryId=dictionary_deployed_info.dictionaryId 
and dictionary_object_map.moid=dictionary_managed_objects.moid
and dictionary_managed_databases.moDBId=dictionary_managed_objects.moDBId
and dictionary_managed_databases.dbname = 'customerservice';
```

the result

[image]

don't understand why output of field dbname still look like this,

Comment: After trimming a VarChar(128) it still might be 128 characters. And the default output in BTEQ is a fixed width report format.

Comment: @dnoeth is it possible to change that?

Comment: BTEQ is mainly for non-interactive batch. If you want to query data you better use a different client like SQL Assistant or Teradata Studio or any 3rd-party.

Comment: @dnoeth i also used teradata studio, but it can not query unity repository,

Comment: Studio is just a client like BTEQ, when you can query using BTEQ you can do the same using Studio, simply use the same user/connection details